# Variable with multiple values in URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

Good morning!

I need to create an URL that contains a variable with many values (array) and also need a JavaScript code that can read those values and store in memory. Example:

http://(...).html?variable=value1|value2|value3

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some thing like this:

url could be: .html?variable=value1,value2,value3

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if( results == null ) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return results[1];
    }
}
var res = getUrlParameter("variable").split(",");
alert(res[0]);
alert(res[1]);
alert(res[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the values in the querystring

```
function AddValues(someValue) {
        var sep = (window.location.href.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&";
        window.location.href = window.location.href + sep + "foo=" + someValue;
    }
    function AddArrayValues() {
    var someValues = ['do', 're', 'mi', 'so', 'la', 'ti', 'do']
        var sep = (window.location.href.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&";
        window.location.href = window.location.href + sep + "fooArray=" + someValues;
    }

<input type="button" onclick="AddValues('someValue')" value="Add Value"/>
<input type="button" onclick="AddArrayValues()" value="Add Values" />
```

Get values from queryString

```
function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }

        alert(vars); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Conventional [querystring structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure) assigns multiple values to a single key:

`http://(...).html?variable=value1&variable=value2&variable=value3`

Then common JS libraries like [`dojo.queryToObject`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/queryToObject.html) can decode it into:

```
{
  variable: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
}
```